# Hard drive usage unreported/ can't find what's taking up space

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

So I have my ubuntu installed on a 500GO NVMe drive, and, because I needed the space, I decided I wanted to relocate it to a 120GO SATA SSD. I figured it would be enough, and, based on my information, it will. The only problem is, Ubuntu disks utility reports that I use 70% of my 500GO drive. So I installed baobab to find and hopefully delete what was taking so much space, but baobab reported something very weird, it said, like disks utility, that the disk is 70% full, but it can only find 50 gigs of files in the root repository. Can anyone help?

[Baobab home screen, showing the drive at 70% capacity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TwYx.png)

[Baobab data analyzer, showing only 57 gigs of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSmbM.png)

Comment: try the `du` utility: `sudo du -hs /  | sort -h`, see if that gives you the same information as the Disk Usage Analyser

Comment: @moo the command you gave me produced the expected result of 323 gigs
now where do I find the difference?

Answer (score 0):

found it, it was Docker build/old containers taking up too much space, leftovers from when I had not yet a script to remove them, and because each of my test images I built was like 6 gigs, it added up very quickly, in `/var/lib/docker/overlay2`